# How to get index of array elements by looping through

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I'm trying to get indices of array elements. I'm going to use it for Leetcode question "Create Target Array in the Given Order".

Right now I wrote the following code but it doesn't work. (returns undefined)

```
var createTargetArray = function(nums) {    

    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        console.log(nums.indexOf[i])
    }

};

const num = [1,2,3,4,0,108];
createTargetArray(num);
```

**Expected output from that code: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]**

Am I using indexOf method incorrectly?

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the function

Comment: You can simply use `i`. It is itself an index.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you, I didn't notice it.

Comment: @Sudhir Ojha Right... you're correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of the numbers, you have to call `indexOf` as a function call (`indexOf(i)`)and not an array accessor (`indexOf[i]`)

Try running the snippet below to check.

```js
var createTargetArray = function(nums) {    

    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        console.log(nums.indexOf(i))
    }

};

const num = [1,2,3,4,0,108];
createTargetArray(num);
```

And if you want the index of exery number, that's just your variable `i`. You don't need to call the `indexOf` method.

```js
var createTargetArray = function(nums) {    

    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        console.log(i)
    }

};

const num = [1,2,3,4,0,108];
createTargetArray(num);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I run the code it returns 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, -1, which is not the correct indices.

Comment: So, do you want the index of 1,2,3,4, 0 and 108?

Comment: Yeah, that's just your variable i. You don't need to use indexOf here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var createTargetArray = function(nums) {    
    for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        console.log(nums.indexOf[i]) // <--mistake
    }
};
```

[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is a method

```
console.log(nums.indexOf(nums[i]));
```

But since you are looping through the array sequentially output will always be [0, 1, 2, ... n]